# How to visualize interval estimate like this in R

Tags: r, visualization

I'm wondering how to create such plot in R.

[image: plot]

Comment: possibly by looking at the code that created that graph? http://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/10858_ee1426c5987143f3a4bc188a31e36b93.html

Comment: to be fair, the code for that particular graph isn't echoed in the document.  I posted the source at http://www.math.mcmaster.ca/bolker/R/misc/bolker_chap.rmd : the code itself is `ggplot(cmod_All,aes(x=var,y=est,ymin=lwr,ymax=upr))+
    geom_pointrange(position=position_dodge(width=0.5),
                    aes(colour=fun,lty=CI))+
    coord_flip()`, but you have to set up the data frame first ...